# check if PropertyDescriptor has attribute

Tags: c#, .net

**I'm trying to check if a property has the DataMemberAttribute applied (using TypeDescriptor)**

this is what I have now:

```
PropertyDescriptor targetProp = targetProps[i];

var has = argetProp.Attributes.Contains(
Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataMemberAttribute).Assembly,typeof(DataMemberAttribute)));
```

the problem is that

```
Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataMemberAttribute).Assembly,typeof(DataMemberAttribute))
```

returns null

Comment: Probably your assembly has no DataMemberAttribute applied. You can't even apply a DataMemberAttribute to an assembly, only properties and fields are allowed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use LINQ. A chain of the [`.OfType<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) and [`.Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697) extension methods would do the job just fine:

```
PropertyDescriptor targetProp = targetProps[i];
bool hasDataMember = targetProp.Attributes.OfType<DataMemberAttribute>().Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a much nicer answer in there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051116/605586

Basically you can just use:

```
bool hasDataMember = Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(DataMemberAttribute));
```

Comment: This won't work on a PropertyDescriptor, only on a PropertyInfo.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways:

- First:

  ```
  PropertyDescriptor targetProp = targetProps[i];
  bool hasDataMember = targetProp.Attributes.Contains(new DataMemberAttribute());
  ```
- Second:

  ```
  PropertyDescriptor targetProp = targetProps[i];
  bool hasDataMember = targetProp.Attributes.OfType<DataMemberAttribute>().Any();
  ```
- Third:

  ```
  PropertyDescriptor targetProp = targetProps[i];
  bool hasDataMember = targetProp.Attributes.Matches(new DataMemberAttribute());
  ```

Best Regard!