# How to determine within code what Validation attributes are applied to MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to iterate through my class properties (may be metaData) to determine which validation (`[Required]` and `[MaxLength]` for example) or other attributes have been applied to those properties.

```
// model is my class

var modelTypeTemp = model.GetType();
var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, modelTypeTemp);
var behaviourAttributes= metaData.GetBehaviourDataAttributes();
var temp2=modelTypeTemp.GetCustomAttributesData();
object[] attrs = modelTypeTemp.GetCustomAttributes(true);

foreach (Attribute attr in attrs)
{
    var temp = attr;
}
```

I have tried different combinations of the code above (Custom and Behaviour attributes) but still can't see the applied attributes.

I want to do this for debugging purposes.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051065/check-if-property-has-attribute?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if property has attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051065/check-if-property-has-attribute)

Comment: Do you have access to the HtmlHelper (the @Html object used on views) object where you are trying to debug?